# "all restraint" or "all restraints"?

Tags: phrase-usage

On [Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/restraint) I found this example:

> 1. With strings and piano, ***all restraint*** vanished.

while on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limb_restraint) I found another:

> 2. ***All restraints*** require a physician's order to be applied.

Does ***all restraint*** mean ***every restraint***? What is the difference between sentence 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) refers to physical devices; each kind needs to be approved by a doctor.

(1) refers to emotional restraint; presumably the musicians were playing uninhibitedly.

Comment: Can we say "all restraints"  to refer to emotions?

Comment: You can find a sentence to work in 'all restraints', but as @Kate shows in her usual crisp way, *restraint* can serve as an abstract concept. So, a composer may lift all restraints from her musicians, including playing in rhythm. She is still dealing with metaphorical chains, not shackles.

Answer (score 0):

A cop can show no, some, or total restraint when arresting you.

A doctor can order you to be restrained with multiple restraints.

The first one describes a behavior that may protect you from harm. The second one describes belts that can tie your hands keeping you from harming yourself or others.